# CakePHP self-join a HABTM table without breaking Cake's automation

Tags: php, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many, cakephp-model

I have a table of athletes.  Athletes have coaches, who are also athletes.  Athletes may have multiple coaches.

To handle this, I have created an athletes table, that uses a join table with an id field, and athlete_id field, and a coach_id field.  Both the athlete_id and coach_id fields point back to the athletes table to the id field.

Normally, according to Cake conventions, I would have to name both of my fields athlete_id, but I have found the following link that shows how to handle that:  http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/view/851/Multiple-relations-to-the-same-model

According to Cake conventions, I would name my join table athletes_athletes, but I'm not sure that will function correctly?  It seems like it might make sense to call it athletes_coaches, but I bet that might break Cake's automatic functionality.

Will this work with the join table being called athletes_athletes?  Is this the right way to do it?  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is my first time answering a question on here, so I apologize ahead of time if my answer is non-standard.  Not too long ago I wrote a social networking app with a User model that had a HABTM self join.  Assuming a join table of 'friends_users', my User model associations looked something like this:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
'Friend' => array(
    'className' => 'User',
    'joinTable' => 'friends_users',
    'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
    'associationForeignKey' => 'friend_id', 
    'unique' => true
)
);
```

Assuming that I wanted to create a listing of the names of all friends for a particular user, I could do something like this.

```
<ul>
<?php foreach($user['User']['Friend'] as $friend): ?>
<li><?php echo $friend['name']; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

So it really doesn't matter what you name your join table (I still try and follow good cake naming conventions) as long as you specify in your HABTM association the new name of the table, the foreignKey and the associatedForeignKey so as to correctly override Cake defaults.  So in your case you could do something like this in your Athlete model (assuming a join table of athletes_coaches):

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
'Coach' => array(
    'className' => 'Athlete',
    'joinTable' => 'athletes_coaches',
    'foreignKey' => 'athlete_id',
    'associationForeignKey' => 'coach_id', 
    'unique' => true
)
);
```

And to display a listing of coaches for a particular athlete (perhaps in the view method of an athlete) you could do something like this:

```
<ul>
<?php foreach($athlete['Athlete']['Coach'] as $coach): ?>
<li><?php echo $coach['name']; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```